# activating conda fails (sourcing ~/.bashrc)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, tcsh

I freshly installed Anaconda (Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64) on "Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS", but activating the installation fails with:

`source ~/.bashrc` returns `Illegal variable name.`

`cat ~/.bashrc`:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/scientia/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/scientia/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/scientia/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/scientia/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

The first line seems to be the reason for that: `__conda_setup="$('/home/scientia/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"`

Comment: that's exactly what I have in my `.bashrc`. What happens when your run `conda activate base` ? Maybe try `conda init bash` ? But that will probably just re-write what you have in the .bashrc already.

Comment: Since this is error seems shell related, can you add the output of `echo $SHELL` to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, the `.bashrc` initialization is bash-specific. However, Conda does also support initialization for csh/tcsh.  Simply run

```
/home/scientia/anaconda3/bin/conda init tcsh
```

then restart your tcsh session and now Conda should be properly configured. You can run the above with a verbose flag `-v` if you want to see what it adds to `.tcshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

First,find your shell through this:

```
echo $Shell
```

if you get:csh, you should input:

```
conda init tcsh
```

or:`./conda init tcsh`
in ~/anaconda3/bin/

Answer (score -1):

I found that I was using the tcsh shell, which doesn't allow syntax like that used in `.bashrc`.

Executing `bash` and then sourcing has worked.

Comment: tcsh isn't even in the same *family* as bash. (Also pertinent: https://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/csh.whynot, https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt -- csh use was defensible back when there were no noncommercially-available shells in the Bourne-derived / POSIX sh family with good interactive features, but that hasn't been true for many decades now).